# Generate a new column in dataframe based on another dataframe and few constraints

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe df1

```
F_Date      B_Date
01/09/2019  02/08/2019
01/09/2019  03/08/2019
02/09/2019  03/08/2019
01/09/2019  04/08/2019
02/09/2019  04/08/2019
03/09/2019  04/08/2019
02/09/2019  05/08/2019
03/09/2019  05/08/2019
04/09/2019  05/08/2019
01/09/2019  06/08/2019
02/09/2019  06/08/2019
03/09/2019  06/08/2019
04/09/2019  06/08/2019
05/09/2019  06/08/2019
02/09/2019  07/08/2019
03/09/2019  07/08/2019
04/09/2019  07/08/2019
05/09/2019  07/08/2019
06/09/2019  07/08/2019
02/09/2019  08/08/2019
03/09/2019  08/08/2019
```

The df has 2 columns such that for each F_Date there are multiple B_Date.

I have another dataframe df2

```
F_Date  Value
01/09/2019  3000
02/09/2019  3700
03/09/2019  4500
04/09/2019  5000
05/09/2019  7000
06/09/2019  8000
07/09/2019  8300
08/09/2019  9000
09/09/2019  9500
10/09/2019  11000
11/09/2019  12500
12/09/2019  14000
13/09/2019  15000
14/09/2019  17000
15/09/2019  17600
16/09/2019  18000
17/09/2019  18500
18/09/2019  18900
19/09/2019  19000
20/09/2019  19400
21/09/2019  19800
22/09/2019  20500
23/09/2019  21000
24/09/2019  21600
25/09/2019  22000
26/09/2019  22100
27/09/2019  22200
28/09/2019  22500
29/09/2019  22800
30/09/2019  23000
```

I want to create a new column value_1 in df1 such that :

for each F_date in df2 there is a value associated. each value needs to be divided in the df1 for multiple entries of F_Date such that the values assigned are increasing. for example :

01/09/2019 has value 3000 in df2 and 01/09/2019 has a total of 51 records in df1. Then 3000 needs to be divided in 51 records such that each value entry is greater than the previous.(create increasing trend). I have sorted the df1 according to F_Date and have entries based on the same.

**Sorted df1 :**

```
01/09/2019  02/08/2019
01/09/2019  02/08/2019
01/09/2019  03/08/2019
01/09/2019  03/08/2019
01/09/2019  04/08/2019
01/09/2019  06/08/2019
01/09/2019  09/08/2019
01/09/2019  10/08/2019
01/09/2019  10/08/2019
01/09/2019  11/08/2019
01/09/2019  12/08/2019
01/09/2019  12/08/2019
01/09/2019  13/08/2019
01/09/2019  13/08/2019
01/09/2019  13/08/2019
01/09/2019  14/08/2019
01/09/2019  14/08/2019
01/09/2019  14/08/2019
01/09/2019  15/08/2019
01/09/2019  16/08/2019
01/09/2019  17/08/2019
01/09/2019  17/08/2019
01/09/2019  18/08/2019
01/09/2019  18/08/2019
```

Can anyone help with the same.

Comment: So you would need the value1 in the df1 to start with, say, 3000/51 and then (3000/51) + 1 and so on? 

Also can you tell what you have tried so far?

Comment: @VinayBharadhwaj Not exactly + 1  but some other value and the assign to all those 51 values so that total ends up as 3000. the catch is that each value should be greater than the first value.

Comment: @VinayBharadhwaj it is not necessary to assign 3000/51 , we can pick lesser value than that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use exp and then normalize

```
import numpy as np
s = np.exp(np.linspace(0,1,51)) 
s = (s * 3000)/ np.sum(s)
np.sum(s)
```

the sum is

```
2999.9999999999995
```

the series is

```
array([34.17786997, 34.86830875, 35.57269531, 36.29131142, 37.02444454,
       37.77238794, 38.53544079, 39.31390833, 40.10810196, 40.91833937,
       41.74494465, 42.58824847, 43.44858816, 44.32630787, 45.22175868,
       46.13529881, 47.06729367, 48.01811607, 48.98814636, 49.97777256,
       50.98739054, 52.01740415, 53.06822542, 54.14027469, 55.23398079,
       56.34978121, 57.4881223 , 58.64945941, 59.83425708, 61.04298925,
       62.27613944, 63.5342009 , 64.8176769 , 66.12708083, 67.46293648,
       68.82577819, 70.21615114, 71.63461149, 73.08172663, 74.55807544,
       76.06424847, 77.60084822, 79.16848934, 80.76779892, 82.39941668,
       84.06399532, 85.76220067, 87.49471205, 89.26222248, 91.06543899,
       92.90508288])
```

part - ii, doing it on whole df

```
joined_df = pd.merge(df_1,df_2,on='F_date')

def add_series(grp):
   n_rows = grp.shape[0]
   val = grp['Value'].min()
   s = np.exp(np.linspace(0,1,n_rows)) 
   s = (s * val)/ np.sum(s)
   grp['col'] = s
   return grp

joined_df.groupby('F_date').apply(add_series)
```

** not tested. but it should give you the idea

Comment: gives what you were looking for?

Comment: If the op needs the number to be a whole number they can round it down, and then add the value that is left to each of the values uniformly in the reverse order

Comment: @vumaasha Thank you for your answer, however for the dataframe, how would we apply your approach on the complete dataset.

Comment: join the dfs, find the row count after join for each f_date. Then groupby f-date and use apply add this series for each group

Comment: @vumaasha Can you please edit your answer according to the same. It would really be helpful.

Comment: @vumaasha Thank you for the edit, I was trying to use the apply for the same but I am getting the following error : `ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types`

Comment: @vumaasha is it possible to add constraint like - 60% of the values lies in the last 10 entries if grouped on the basis of F_date and 40% in the rest. so for example, when sorted, there are 21 entries in df1. 60% of the value is assigned to last 10 values and rest 40% to the remaining and still maintain the increasing trend.